# Add Video Length to Doc Library or File Size to Asset Library

Tags: sharepoint-designer, document-library, asset-library

I want to store videos in a library that can automatically identify both the file size and the video length. To get the file size, have to use a document library. The field is an option when modifying an asset library view, but it is always blank. To get the video length, I have to use the asset library. How can I get both items in the same library?